# JavaScript : accessing array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am new to java script and i need some help with following code sample.

basically i want to know how can i access the values in the following array

```
$('#sheet').sheet({
                   title: "${title}",
                   buildSheet: true,
                   workbook: "${sheet}"
               });
```

this workbook : "${sheet}" contains 2d array.

actually i have forloop to print `workbook : ${sheet}`  content

```
<c:forEach var="sheet" items="${workbook}">
                       <table>
                     <c:forEach var="row" items="${sheet}">
                             <tr>
                             <c:forEach var="cell" items="${row}">
                         <td>test test</td>
                       </c:forEach>
                       </tr>
                     </c:forEach>
                   </table>
           </c:forEach>
```

basically i want to loop through values inside `workbook` variable

i really appreciate any help with that. 
thanks for looking into this

Comment: can you post the HTML your template outputs instead of the template?

Comment: it does not output anything, blank page..

Comment: but when i debug jquery, i can see workbook is holding pointer to memory location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jquery.each()

```
$.each(your2darray, function(key, value) {
   alert('key : ' + key + 'value:' + value);
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

The 2D array is actually a JavaScript object, which function similar to a dictionary or map in other programming languages. You can get the values by passing the keys into the object.

example:

```
myObject = { 'key' : 'value' }
//get the value 
var myValue = myObject['key'];
alert(myValue);
```

Comment: but i am confused with the way my variable is assigned, it is not like the way myObject variable is assigned. your myObject variable is assigned using equal sign but mine is different

Comment: I assumed that sheet() is a function and can access its parameters in the manner I showed. Maybe I was wrong.